# Are git submodules reasonably usable?

Tags: git, git-submodules

I've read many caveats with using git submodules.

In essense, I have my personal repository. And I would like to import another actively-maintained repository that I could add as a framework to the original project.

It it reasonable to use git submodules? Is that what the "GitHub crowd" do?

Comment: Some people use them, some people don't. Voting to close as "not constructive", sorry.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the feedback on the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a look at this blog post. It should give you a great overview:

[Understanding git submodules](http://speirs.org/blog/2009/5/11/understanding-git-submodules.html)